# Sequential gganimate plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I'm trying to create an animated time series plot using `gganimate`. The following code produces almost the desired output. It creates two random time series, constructs a data frame and renders the desired animation:

```
# necessary packages
require(ggplot2)
require(gganimate)
require(transformr)
require(gifski)

# construct data frame with two random time series and time index t
TS      = matrix(rnorm(100 * 2), 100, 2)
plot.df = data.frame(TS, t = 1:100)
plot.df = reshape2::melt(plot.df, id.vars = "t")

# usual ggplot line plot structure
p = ggplot(plot.df, aes(x = t, y = value, col = variable)) + 
  geom_line()
  
# animation that reveals time series along time dimension (= x-axis)
play = p + transition_reveal(t)

# render plot using gifski
animate(play,renderer = gifski_renderer())
```

[In the output, both time series are revealed at the same time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stPIq.jpg) Is there an option to first reveal the first time series and then reveal the second time series on top of the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a workaround that could help. The idea is to create a new column that is a progressive from 1 to `nrow` of the dataset and use it in the `transition_reveal()`:
Obviously the dataset should be ordered by time and variabiles like in your data.

```
# necessary packages
require(ggplot2)
require(gganimate)
require(gifski)

# construct data frame with two random time series and time index t
TS      <- matrix(rnorm(100 * 2), 100, 2)
plot.df <- data.frame(TS, t = 1:100)
plot.df <- reshape2::melt(plot.df, id.vars = "t")

# reorder in case
# plot.df <- plot.df[order(plot.df$variable,plot.df$t),]

# adding a new column to make progressive the reveal of the data
plot.df$transition_value <- 1:nrow(plot.df)

# your ggplot plot
p <- ggplot(plot.df, aes(x = t, y = value, col = variable)) + 
  geom_line()

# reveal with the new value
play <- p + transition_reveal(transition_value)

# render plot using gifski
animate(play,renderer = gifski_renderer())
```

[image]

Comment: Very elegant and much more obvious than I'd expected, thanks!